# Ember: Must include an 'id' in an object passed to 'push'

Tags: serialization, ember.js, ember-data

Currently experiencing the following error: `You must include an 'id' for failed-shotlist in an object passed to 'push'`. This is in a code base I have inherited mid-development and I am fairly new to Ember.

From what I understand, this occurs when the backend does not respond with an ID. The server payload looks like the following (returning an alert object with an embedded failedShotlist record):

```
alertAuthor: "Test name"
alertDate:"2018-06-28T16:25:21+12:00"
alertIdentifier:"456e15c7-7a8b-11e8-84a8-06f4aef780e3"
alertType:"failedShotlist"
email:"test@gmail.com"
failedShotlist:
    projectIdentifier:"79050dfb-5faf-11e8-84a8-06f4aef780e3"
    projectName:"8888 st"
    projectRoleENUM:"bp"
    projectRoleName:"Building Participant"
    shotlistDescription:"Framing"
    shotlistIdentifier:"79d52773-5faf-11e8-84a8-06f4aef780e3"
inviteIdentifier:null
profileId:"c4e02bee-3d26-11e8-84a8-06f4aef780e3"
shotlistIdentifier:"79d52773-5faf-11e8-84a8-06f4aef780e3"
```

Since the backend doesn't respond with an ID attr, the primary key needs to be transformed using a serializer's 'primaryKey' property:

**serializers/alert.js**

```
export default ApplicationSerializer.extend(EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  primaryKey: 'alertIdentifier',

  attrs: {
    'invite': { deserialize: 'records' },
    'failedShotlist': { deserialize: 'records' },
  },
});
```

I couldn't find any mention of this, but I assume that embedded records are further serialized by their own serializers. The existing one is as follows:

**serializers/failedShotlist.js**

```
export default ApplicationSerializer.extend({
  attrs: {
    'shotlistId': { key: 'shotlistIdentifier' },
    'projectId': { key: 'projectIdentifier' },
  },
});
```

Since the ID's for the failedShotlist object also need to be transformed, I have updated this to include the primaryKey prop:

**serializers/failedShotlist.js**

```
export default ApplicationSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: 'shotlistIdentifier',

  attrs: {
    'shotlistId': { key: 'shotlistIdentifier' },
    'projectId': { key: 'projectIdentifier' },
  },
});
```

Unfortunately, this results in the same error I originally encountered. Any ideas as to how this might be resolved?

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in [`extractId`](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.2/classes/DS.JSONSerializer/methods/extractId?anchor=extractId) or [`normalize`](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.2/classes/DS.JSONSerializer/methods/normalize?anchor=normalize) methods of your application serializer (assuming you are not overriding these functions) and verify that ID is extracted correctly?

Comment: @jelhan - adding `console.log(this.extractId(modelClass, resourceHash));` inside the application.js serializer's `normalize` method returns the appropriate ID for the alert records, while null for the embedded failed-shotlist records. So I guess the ID is not being extracted correctly? How might this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something I had overlooked was that the source files for the adapter and the serializer weren't following the naming convention of the rest of the codebase.

Where the serializer was called `failedShotlist.js`, the model related to it was called `failed-shotlist.js`.

Renaming the serializer file to `failed-shotlist.js` allowed my existing code to work:

```
export default ApplicationSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: 'shotlistIdentifier'
}
```

Comment: ember-cli is always using kebab-case for file names. I would recommend using the build in generators (`ember help generate`) to avoid such issues.

Comment: @jelhan - good to know. These were files created before my involvement in the codebase.